# Admob_plus_cordova is not working in android

Tags: admob, cordova-plugins, cordova-admob

issue is to implement admob add in my cordova project.

Tried all , cordova plugin admob free as well as plus but none of them worked.
I tried multiple variation of below code
My ad specific code is in separate js file (www/js/myads.js)

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', async () => {
   
  await admob.start();

  banner = new admob.BannerAd({
    adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111',
  });

  banner.on('impression', async (evt) => {
    await banner.hide()
  });

  await banner.show();
  
   
  }, false);
```